# Is there an explosive method to destroying enemy helicopters while on foot?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

We have been playing this game on the hardest difficulty and the biggest pain we have experienced so far are the enemy helicopters while we are on foot.  Is there a way to shoot down an enemy helicopter without using bullets? I ask as it is challenging trying to shoot the pilot while being exposed to the gunner passengers.

Perhaps is there a Ground-to-Air missile weapon crate I can find?  If so, where is it?

Comment: I know you specifically forbid bullets, but with the vehicle damage upgrade and the UPlay reward Llama SIG552 you can shoot them down with a few rounds to the fuselage.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that vehicle damage upgrade! I don't think I have spent points in that skill yet but I do have that SIG552.  Thank you for that idea!

Comment: Did you try using assault rifle mounted grenades launcher? If no, I'll make an answer about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal technique: I use assault rifle mounted grenade launcher. You do not have access to it directly at the beginning of the game, but still within the first area.

Just wait for the helicopter to be just above you, then fire your grenade launcher until the helicopter is down.

Comment: this is the preferred troll method as well!

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this is the HT1, sniper rifle.
It is a anti material rifle, and one shot is enought for any and all helicopter (2 with silencer).

Without bullet, you can try the drone (Explosive or IEM) or grenade launcher.

Comment: The drone works very well even on the Unidad Apache